# How do I get this JavaScript to repeat

Tags: javascript

```
var progress = document.querySelector('.progress-done');

setTimeout(() => {
progress.style.width = progress.getAttribute('data-done') + '%';
progress.style.opacity = 1;
}, 500)
```

I have made a progress bar. I want it to repeat with the same Selector and the same Attribute. How would I do this?

Comment: You need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval and you're done.

Comment: Please add all code so that we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

You have to use `setIntervall()` instead of `setTimeout`.

### Difference

The **difference** between these two is

- **setTimeout** allows us to run a function **once** after the interval of time.
- **setInterval** allows us to run a function **repeatedly**, starting after the interval of time, then repeating continuously at that interval.

### Example

**x** is how often it should repeat in milliseconds

```
setIntervall(() => {
  progress.style.width = progress.getAttribute('data-done') + '%';
  progress.style.opacity = 1;
}, x);
```

More Informations you can finde here

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
- https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. Include the relevant parts of the link _in the answer itself_. Link-only answers are less useful.

Comment: okay, I will update it. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Change setTimeout to setInterval

```
setInterval(() => {
progress.style.width = progress.getAttribute('data-done') + '%';
progress.style.opacity = 1;
}, 500)
```